# Angularjs translate provider prefix issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angular translate module having difficulties in finding the right folder structure. Following are my folder structure:

```
public
 -assets
    -js
    -cs
    -il8n
     -en.json
 -controllers
 -directives
 -app.js
```

My translate provider app config as follow:

```
myApp.config(['$translateProvider',
function ($translateProvider) {

    // prefix and suffix information  is required to specify a pattern
    // You can simply use the static-files loader with this pattern:
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: 'assets/i18n/',
        suffix: '.json'
    });

    // Since you've now registered more then one translation table, angular-translate has to know which one to use.
    // This is where preferredLanguage(langKey) comes in.
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

    // Store the language in the local storage
    $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();

}]);
```

The error I receiving:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/assets/i18n/en.json 404 (Not Found)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think this is silly, but the folder name is incorrect since it use an L instead of a 1, should be 'i18n'.

Comment: may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24744774/how-to-best-organize-translation-strings-in-angular-translate

Comment: @Lucio  Ya, thanks. It sort out now

Answer (score 2):

I guess everything you config about `$translateProvider` is correct.

By seeing your error can say that path to get that JSON file is not correct.

I guess your JSON file is located in **il8n**. Here the letter before **8** is **l** not **1(one)**.

By renaming your folder from **il8n** to **i18n** will resolve your problem.